# Where does the "tmpfs" file system reside?

Tags: linux, tmpfs

Where does the `tmpfs` file system reside? In RAM or swap?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: There's no request for learning materials here that I can see.

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither.  It resides in the page cache, and those pages will get swapped out just like any other 'dirty' pages do when there's memory pressure.

Answer (score 4):

`tmpfs` filesystems (and thus `devtmpfs` filesytems) are implemented in Linux as essentially parts of the file and directory caches that have no persistent backing storage.  The file data are, unlike `ramfs` filesystems, swappable however.  So the file data can be either in physical RAM or held on a swap volume on a disc.

Note the plural, by the way.  It is possible, and indeed usual with systems like the nosh `system-manager` and systemd, to have multiple `tmpfs` filesystems.

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/894468/38062
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`system-manager`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/system-manager.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Linus Torvalds et al. (2005).  [`Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt).  Linux.  GitHub.
- Rob Landley et al. (2005). [`Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt).  Linux.  GitHub.